# Dynamic embed file got cached on Gmail

Tags: php, gmail

I'm developing a backend link (PHP) to generate GIF file to show countdown timer but every time I refresh it loads image same as first reading.
In the backend, it generates the time base on current time by arranging 60 numbers into timer and that GIF file 60 seconds long.
**Example**:
End date will be 11:00PM
Read email at 9:00PM
Timer shows 2 hours left. One hour later, I come and still see 2 hours on timer

Sample link: https://abc.test.com/gif/47_1666713355626.gif
[image]

How to avoid cache on Gmail and Apple Mail please as I have tried on yahoo mail, it works fine

Not sure if has anyway to make querystring on embed link dynamically

Comment: Please post relevant PHP code.

Comment: Are you setting expiration and no cache headers on the image? If that isn't working still, you could potentially 302 redirect the image URL to another URL with a random (or timestamp-based) portion of the URL which might also bust caches